# When does selectedCell change?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I have an NSTableView and I want to do something whenever the selectedCell element changes.

So, my table view is called tableView, and this is what I want to observe:

```
[tableView selectedCell]
```

I tried using key-value observing, but that didn't seem to work, or maybe I was doing it wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Most properties of Cocoa's own classes are not observable. If a property is observable, the documentation for it will explicitly say so; if the documentation doesn't say a property is observable, assume it isn't.

<del>Furthermore, properties that don't exist are doubly not observable. The documentation for [NSTableView](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/) and [NSOutlineView](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/) both mention no method named “`selectedCell`”. You should assume there isn't one.</del>

If you want to know when the user selects a different row, be the table view's delegate; it sends delegate messages for that, if you'll respond to them.

Comment: selectedCell is a method of NSControl, which NSTableView inherits from. Is there some other way I can be notified that the cursor is in a new cell in an NSTableView?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I always forget that table views have the control nature. Even so, I'm not sure `selectedCell` works on a table view. As for detecting when the user is editing a cell, there are delegate methods for that, too.

Comment: By the way, if you're just trying to make your data editable, working on the cell-by-cell level is not the way to do it. Either be the data source and implement `tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:`, or bind your table column to a controller holding an array and make sure that the controller allows editing and the model objects are mutable (which they should be, unless you made them otherwise).

Answer (score -1):

`NSTableView` will use one and only one `dataCell` object for each column. `selectedCell` is the wrong way. You can use `selectedColumn` to get the selected column and then ask for its `dataCell`.

And: I guess you are searching for NSTableView delegate methods 
`tableViewSelectionDidChange:` and `tableViewSelectionIsChanging:`